# How do i call both variables even though both of them have a same number values

Tags: java

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    if (winnerPlayer <= sumPlayer[i]){
        runnerupPlayer = winnerPlayer;
        winnerPlayer = sumPlayer[i];
    } else if (runnerupPlayer <= sumPlayer[i]){
        runnerupPlayer = sumPlayer[i];
    }
}

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    if (winnerPlayer == sumPlayer[i]){
        winnerPlayerNumber = i+1;
    }
    if (runnerupPlayer <= winnerPlayer){
        runnerupPlayerNumber = i+1;
    }
}

System.out.println("\nWinner: Player " + winnerPlayerNumber + " by winning " + winnerPlayer + " win sets.");
System.out.println("Runner-up: Player " + runnerupPlayerNumber + " by winning " + runnerupPlayer + " win sets.");
```

For example if player 1 and player 5 have 4 points, the output reads:

```
Winner: Player 5 by winning 4 win sets.
Runner-up: Player 5 by winning 4 win sets.
```

I want it to be like this:

```
Winner: Player 1 by winning 4 win sets.
Runner-up: Player 5 by winning 4 win sets.
```

How do I call both player 1 and player 5 at the same time in the output?

Here's my full code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class pingPongTour {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[][] player = new int[5][5];
        int[][] playerPoints = new int[5][5];

        System.out.println("Welcome to PingPong Tournament Point System!");
        System.out.println("\nPlayer 1 vs Player 2");
        System.out.print("Player 1 score:");
        player[0][1] = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Player 2 score:");
        player[1][0] = in.nextInt();
        if (player[0][1] > 0) {
            playerPoints[0][1] = 2;
        }
        else {
            playerPoints[1][0] = 2;
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Player 3 vs Player 4");
        System.out.print("Player 3 score:");
        player[2][3] = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Player 4 score:");
        player[3][2] = in.nextInt();
        if (player[2][3] > 0) {
            playerPoints[2][3] = 2;
        }
        else {
            playerPoints[3][2] = 2;
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Player 5 vs Player 1");
        System.out.print("Player 5 score:");
        player[4][0] = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Player 1 score:");
        player[0][4] = in.nextInt();
        if (player[4][0] > 0) {
            playerPoints[4][0] = 2;
        }
        else {
            playerPoints[0][4] = 2;
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Player 2 vs Player 3");
        System.out.print("Player 2 score:");
        player[1][2] = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Player 3 score:");
        player[2][1] = in.nextInt();
        if (player[1][2] > 0) {
            playerPoints[1][2] = 2;
        }
        else {
            playerPoints[2][1] = 2;
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Player 4 vs Player 5");
        System.out.print("Player 4 score:");
        player[3][4] = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Player 5 score:");
        player[4][3] = in.nextInt();
        if (player[3][4] > 0) {
            playerPoints[3][4] = 2;
        }
        else {
            playerPoints[4][3] = 2;
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Player 1 vs Player 3");
        System.out.print("Player 1 score:");
        player[0][2] = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Player 3 score:");
        player[2][0] = in.nextInt();
        if (player[0][2] > 0) {
            playerPoints[0][2] = 2;
        }
        else {
            playerPoints[2][0] = 2;
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Player 2 vs Player 4");
        System.out.print("Player 2 score:");
        player[1][3] = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Player 4 score:");
        player[3][1] = in.nextInt();
        if (player[1][3] > 0) {
            playerPoints[1][3] = 2;
        }
        else {
            playerPoints[3][1] = 2;
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Player 5 vs Player 3");
        System.out.print("Player 5 score:");
        player[4][2] = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Player 3 score:");
        player[2][4] = in.nextInt();
        if (player[4][2] > 0) {
            playerPoints[4][2] = 2;
        }
        else {
            playerPoints[2][4] = 2;
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Player 1 vs Player 4");
        System.out.print("Player 1 score:");
        player[0][3] = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Player 4 score:");
        player[3][0] = in.nextInt();
        if (player[0][3] > 0) {
            playerPoints[0][3] = 2;
        }
        else {
            playerPoints[3][0] = 2;
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Player 2 vs Player 5");
        System.out.print("Player 2 score:");
        player[1][4] = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Player 5 score:");
        player[4][1] = in.nextInt();
        if (player[1][4] > 0) {
            playerPoints[1][4] = 2;
        }
        else {
            playerPoints[4][1] = 2;
        }
        System.out.println();

        int[] sumPlayer = new int[5];
        int[] sumPlayerPoints = new int[5];
        int winnerPlayer = 0;
        int runnerupPlayer = 0;
        int winnerPlayerNumber = 0;
        int runnerupPlayerNumber = 0;

        sumPlayer[0] = (player[0][1] + player[0][2] + player[0][3] + player[0][4]);
        sumPlayer[1] = (player[1][0] + player[1][2] + player[1][3] + player[1][4]);
        sumPlayer[2] = (player[2][0] + player[2][1] + player[2][3] + player[2][4]);
        sumPlayer[3] = (player[3][0] + player[3][1] + player[3][2] + player[3][4]);
        sumPlayer[4] = (player[4][0] + player[4][1] + player[4][2] + player[4][3]);

        sumPlayerPoints[0] = (playerPoints[0][1] + playerPoints[0][2] + playerPoints[0][3] + playerPoints[0][4]);
        sumPlayerPoints[1] = (playerPoints[1][0] + playerPoints[1][2] + playerPoints[1][3] + playerPoints[1][4]);
        sumPlayerPoints[2] = (playerPoints[2][0] + playerPoints[2][1] + playerPoints[2][3] + playerPoints[2][4]);
        sumPlayerPoints[3] = (playerPoints[3][0] + playerPoints[3][1] + playerPoints[3][2] + playerPoints[3][4]);
        sumPlayerPoints[4] = (playerPoints[4][0] + playerPoints[4][1] + playerPoints[4][2] + playerPoints[4][3]);

        System.out.println("Set points:-");
        System.out.println("Player 1: " + sumPlayer[0]);
        System.out.println("Player 2: " + sumPlayer[1]);
        System.out.println("Player 3: " + sumPlayer[2]);
        System.out.println("Player 4: " + sumPlayer[3]);
        System.out.println("Player 5: " + sumPlayer[4]);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Win points:-");
        System.out.println("Player 1: " + sumPlayerPoints[0]);
        System.out.println("Player 2: " + sumPlayerPoints[1]);
        System.out.println("Player 3: " + sumPlayerPoints[2]);
        System.out.println("Player 4: " + sumPlayerPoints[3]);
        System.out.println("Player 5: " + sumPlayerPoints[4]);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (winnerPlayer <= sumPlayer[i]) {
                runnerupPlayer = winnerPlayer;
                winnerPlayer = sumPlayer[i];
            }
            else if (runnerupPlayer <= sumPlayer[i]) {
                runnerupPlayer = sumPlayer[i];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (winnerPlayer == sumPlayer[i]) {
                winnerPlayerNumber = i + 1;
            }
            if (runnerupPlayer <= winnerPlayer) {
                runnerupPlayerNumber = i + 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nWinner: Player " + winnerPlayerNumber + " by winning " + winnerPlayer + " win sets.");
        System.out.println("Runner-up: Player " + runnerupPlayerNumber + " by winning " + runnerupPlayer + " win sets.");
    }
}
```

Comment: already edited my post, you can review my code at the post.

Comment: "How do I call both player 1 and player 5 at the same time in the output?" I can't understand what this is supposed to mean. Variables are not "called", and neither are array elements. Only methods are called in Java. I also don't know what you mean by "at the same time". It seems like the problem is that the wrong player number is reported in the results. To understand why, please start by trying to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the code and create a [mre].